# c++: initializing a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to copy a program from my textbook. it looks like i've done everything right except for one thing: i can't figure out how to initialize the multidimensional array i need to get the output that's printed in the book.

the program is supposed to print a two dimensional array. one column is the student ID number (between 1 and 4), another column is their average quiz grade, and there are three columns under the heading "Quizzes" which list each of their individual quiz grades. when i run the program i get a bunch of random numbers for the results, and i think this is because i haven't figured out how to put together the data that i need for this example.

the book didn't give the code for filling this array even though it didn't offer any clear examples of how to do this. i've checked some examples of multidimensional array initialization online, but i can't figure out how to apply anything i've read to this specific situation.

thank you in advance for any insight.

```
#include <iostream>

//necessary to use setw()
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int NUMBER_STUDENTS = 4, NUMBER_QUIZZES = 3;

void computeStAve(const int grade[][NUMBER_QUIZZES], double stAve[]);

void computeQuizAve(const int grade[][NUMBER_QUIZZES], double quizAve[]);

void display(const int grade[][NUMBER_QUIZZES], const double stAve[], const double quizAve[]);

int main() {

  int grade[NUMBER_STUDENTS][NUMBER_QUIZZES];

//giving my own values for stAve[] and quizAve[]

  double stAve[NUMBER_STUDENTS] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  double quizAve[NUMBER_QUIZZES] = {7.0, 5.0, 7.5};



  computeStAve(grade, stAve);
  computeQuizAve(grade, quizAve);
  display(grade, stAve, quizAve);

  return 0;

}


void computeStAve(const int grade[][NUMBER_QUIZZES], double stAve[]){

  for (int stNum = 1; stNum <= NUMBER_STUDENTS; stNum++){

    double sum = 0;

    for (int quizNum = 1; quizNum <= NUMBER_QUIZZES; quizNum++){

      sum = sum + grade[stNum - 1][quizNum - 1];

      stAve[stNum - 1] = sum / NUMBER_QUIZZES;

    }

  }

}


void computeQuizAve(const int grade[][NUMBER_QUIZZES], double quizAve[]){

  for (int quizNum = 1; quizNum <= NUMBER_QUIZZES; quizNum++){

    double sum = 0;

    for (int stNum = 1; stNum <= NUMBER_STUDENTS; stNum++){

      sum = sum + grade[stNum - 1][quizNum - 1];

      quizAve[quizNum - 1] = sum / NUMBER_STUDENTS;

    }

  }

}


void display(const int grade[][NUMBER_QUIZZES], const double stAve[], const double quizAve[]){

  cout << setw(10) << "Student";
  cout << setw(5) << "Ave";
  cout << setw(15) << "Quizzes" << endl;

  for (int stNum = 1; stNum <= NUMBER_STUDENTS; stNum++){

    cout << setw(10) << stNum;
    cout << setw(5) << stAve[stNum - 1] << " ";

    for (int quizNum = 1; quizNum <= NUMBER_QUIZZES; quizNum++){

      cout << setw(5) << grade[stNum - 1][quizNum - 1];

    }

    cout << endl;

  }

  cout << "Quiz averages: ";

  for (int quizNum = 1; quizNum <= NUMBER_QUIZZES; quizNum++){

    cout << setw(5) << quizAve[quizNum - 1];
    cout << endl;

  }

}
```

Comment: Google is your friend. E.g.: [Initialization of a multidimensional arrays in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-44/)

Comment: `std::vector` has been around even longer than that ....

Comment: Are we speaking about init. of `int grade[NUMBER_STUDENTS][NUMBER_QUIZZES];`? It's an array (with `NUMBER_STUDENTS` elements) where each element is an array (with `NUMBER_QUIZZES` elements) of `int`. So, the init. of inner arrays could be e.g. `{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }`, and the init. of outer array respectively e.g. `{ { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 } }`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: To what do you need the array initialized? I'd expect zero, but I'm willing to be surprised. Here's [a link to a documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) covering the many initialization options available in modern C++

Comment: @Scheff, thank you for that. my program is working now.